# Name should be less than 13 characters, or less than 14 if last character is between 1-5 or a-j

Tags: eosjs

i am facing this error when i hit my Post API,Basically i am creating this API for propose the Multisig Transaction. And i am follow the documentation of EOSJS from offical website of EOSIO. MY naming convention is follow which is mention but still facing error

MY API IS

```
app.post('/propose', async (req, res) => {
  
 const actions = [{ 
  account: 'eosio',
  name: 'updateauth',
  authorization: [{
  actor: 'adeelabbasna',
  permission: 'active',
  }],
  data: {
     account: 'adeelabbasna', 
     permission: 'active',
     parent: '',
     auth: {
      threshold: 1,
     keys: [{ 
        key: 'EOS7BJChRpdmRbwLgdR2MPW4f7BkXye21quFxqN2Pjv8tJy6iejpF',
        weight: 1
        }],

    accounts: [],
   waits: []}
},

}];



     (async () => {

      const serialized_actions = await api.serializeActions(actions)

      proposeInput = {
      proposer: 'adeelabbasna',
      proposal_name: 'changeowner',
      requested: [{
              actor: 'adeelabbasna',
              permission: 'active'
          },
          {
              actor: 'rajazahoor11',
              permission: 'active'
          }
      ],
      trx: {
          expiration: '2019-09-16T16:39:15',
          ref_block_num: 0,
          ref_block_prefix: 0,
          max_net_usage_words: 0,
          max_cpu_usage_ms: 0,
          delay_sec: 0,
          context_free_actions: [],
          actions: serialized_actions,
          transaction_extensions: []
      }

  };
  const result = await api.transact({
      actions: [{
          account: 'eosio.msig',
          name: 'propose',
          authorization: [{
              actor: 'adeelabbasna',
              permission: 'active',
          }],
          data: proposeInput,
      }]
  }, 
{
      blocksBehind: 3,
      expireSeconds: 30,
      broadcast: true,
      sign: true
  });

           })();
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[image]
And then this error will come

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Name should be less than 13 characters, or less than 14 if last character is between 1-5 or a-j, and only contain the following symbols .12345abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
at SerialBuffer.pushName (/home/adeel/Documents/EOSIO apis/Multisig Transaction/Propose/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:253:19)
at Object.serialize (/home/adeel/Documents/EOSIO apis/Multisig Transaction/Propose/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:841:57)
at Object.serializeStruct [as serialize] (/home/adeel/Documents/EOSIO apis/Multisig Transaction/Propose/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:591:28)
at Object.exports.serializeActionData (/home/adeel/Documents/EOSIO apis/Multisig Transaction/Propose/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:1070:12)
at Object.exports.serializeAction (/home/adeel/Documents/EOSIO apis/Multisig Transaction/Propose/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-serialize.js:1079:23)
at Api. (/home/adeel/Documents/EOSIO apis/Multisig Transaction/Propose/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:311:71)
at step (/home/adeel/Documents/EOSIO apis/Multisig Transaction/Propose/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:49:23)
at Object.next (/home/adeel/Documents/EOSIO apis/Multisig Transaction/Propose/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:30:53)
at fulfilled (/home/adeel/Documents/EOSIO apis/Multisig Transaction/Propose/node_modules/eosjs/dist/eosjs-api.js:21:58)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:26207) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:26207) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
i also attached Screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Set `owner` to the parent of authority.

```
app.post('/propose', async (req, res) => {
  
 const actions = [{ 
  account: 'eosio',
  name: 'updateauth',
  authorization: [{
  actor: 'adeelabbasna',
  permission: 'active',
  }],
  data: {
     account: 'adeelabbasna', 
     permission: 'active',
     parent: 'owner', // HERE!
     auth: {
      threshold: 1,
     keys: [{ 
        key: 'EOS7BJChRpdmRbwLgdR2MPW4f7BkXye21quFxqN2Pjv8tJy6iejpF',
        weight: 1
        }],

    accounts: [],
   waits: []}
},

}];
```

Comment: yeah you right but here one more solution

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/issues/799